# Remove leading zeros in batch file

Tags: batch-file, zero, trim

In my application, I get a number having leading zeros. I am trying to trim the leading zeros and get the actual number. I tried using `/a` switch which considers right side of the assignment as an arithmetic expression. So I tried:

```
SET /a N = 00027
```

The above gave me the output of **23** which is the decimal equivalent of octal number **27**. Then I found [this solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/alt.msdos.batch.nt/WbUgca7IBsU) online.

```
SET N = 00027
SET /a N = 1%N%-(11%N%-1%N%)/10
```

This seems working and is giving the output **27**. Is there much easier way to trim the leading zeros in a batch file?

Comment: Not that I can find. :-) The problem is that, as you can see, the leading zero without a following `x` indicates that you're using an octal number (`0x0027` indicates a hex number). The only way to remove it is to concatenate a non-zero value on the left to make it appear to be a decimal value and then remove the amount added. (You can see the number formats supported by using a known invalid value in the operation, like `set /a N=d/1`, which produces 'Invalid number.  Numeric constants are either decimal (17), hexadecimal (0x11), or octal (021).".

Comment: You found a one-liner solution that does what you want. What else do you need? :)

Comment: See also: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_leadingzero.php

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The method you found is very good. It supports numbers up to 99,999,999 and is very fast.

There is a simpler way to use SET /A that works with numbers up to 9999. It uses the modulus operation. The method cannot be extended to larger numbers.

```
 set n=0027
 set /a n=10000%n% %% 10000
```

The FOR /F method that Dale posted works with "any" size number (up to 8191 digits). However, it needs just a bit more work to handle zero values.

```
set n=000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000027
for /f "tokens=* delims=0" %%N in ("%n%") do set "n=%%N"
if not defined n set "n=0"
```

Comment: Looks like the `for /f` method doesn't work for only zeros, since the `for/f` sets `n` to nothing.
I would rather check for zero like this: ```if not defined n set /a n = 0```

Comment: @timlg07 - OMG! I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote that. Actually I do - I was thinking that the loop would not iterate because there was no value, but that is only true if `"%n%"` is empty or contains whitespace. But I never bothered to test (boo to me). I am shocked you are the first person to point out the error. I've fixed the post. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I found this problem when trying to solve a similar issue myself.  I liked your solution until I realized there is a slightly better way:

```
SET /a N=1%N%+1%N%-2%N%
```

Answer (score 6):

The exit command is pretty good at clearing leading zeros:

```
>set n=0000890

>cmd /c exit /b %n%

>echo %errorlevel%
890
```

With this you can use number up to 32 bit integer limit and the piece of code is really small, despite additional call of cmd.exe could harm the performance.

Comment: +1, Good method, but you need to be aware of the limitations. ERRORLEVEL is a signed 32 bit integer with a value between -2147483648 and 2147483647. An EXIT value that exceeds those limits will be transformed to one within the limits. For example, EXIT 4000000000 is reported as ERRORLEVEL -294967296.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `FOR /F` to remove leading zeros.

```
C:\>SET n=00030
echo off
for /f "tokens=* delims=0" %a in ("%n%") DO echo %a
30
```

As you can see, the `delims` is set to 0. This will makes 0 as a delimiter. At the same time with `tokens` of `*` this will ensure that the leading 0's will be removed while the rest of the line will be processed (including trailing 0's).

You may refer to [this link](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_leadingzero.php) for more information about removal of leading 0's.

P.S. Do remember to use `%%a` instead of `%a` when you are running on batch file in `FOR /F`.