# batch file to handle month 08 as not valid octal

Tags: batch-file

```
if /i %dd% LSS 10 set dd=%date:~8,1%

set /A dd=%dd% - 1

set /A mm=%mm% + 0
```

The above piece of script takes system date and when the month is August and date is 1st it is encountered with error.

> Invalid number.  Numeric constants are either decimal (17),
>   hexadecimal (0x11), or octal (021).

Probably there is issue with '08', which is not a valid octal number.
So how do a manage the month of August with number 08.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Why are you adding zero `%mm% + 0` to the month?  Full context of the code can help in finding the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

The code can use.

`set /A %Variable% = 1%Variable% -100`

Assume %Variable% = 08

%Variable% = 1%Variable% -100

→ %Variable% = 108 - 100 = 8

Adding the code in the case.

`set /A dd=1%dd%-100
set /A dd=%dd% - 1`

Answer (score 0):

assuming your date format is `Mo 08/12/2013`:

```
set /a day=1%date:~6,2%-100
set /a month=1%date:~3,2%-100
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Remove leading zeros in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762813/remove-leading-zeros-in-batch-file), should work with the following:

```
cmd /c exit /b %dd%
set dd=%errorlevel%

cmd /c exit /b %mm%
set mm=%errorlevel%

set /A dd=%dd% - 1

set /A mm=%mm% + 0
```