# Finding biggest number between two characters

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to find biggest number between `[` and `]`. So far I got nothing.

Example text file:

```
a.(1234)[00012]
bb.(4321)[00100]
ccc.(9876)[10101]
dd.(6789)[01010]
e.(5555)[00021]
```

Desired output:

```
10101
```

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: Like i said on my post i got nothing. I dont even know where to start.

Comment: Why are you using batch files for that? Try python, it will be a lot easier.

Comment: I am trying to learn batch programming as much as i could. Yes batch is like trying to capture fly with a chopstick compare it with more advenced languages. Noone can denial. But there is a special beaute in it.

Comment: For me, batch is more difficult than Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET /a maxnum=0
SET "maxraw="
FOR /f "tokens=2delims=[]" %%a IN (q27649334.txt) DO CALL :max %%a
ECHO maximum is "%maxraw%" with value %maxnum%

GOTO :EOF

:max
SET candidate=%1
:maxl
IF NOT "%candidate%"=="0" IF "%candidate:~0,1%"=="0" SET "candidate=%candidate:~1%"&GOTO maxl
IF %candidate% lss %maxnum% GOTO :EOF 
SET /a maxnum=candidate
:setmax
SET "maxraw=%1"
GOTO :eof
```

I used a file named `q27649334.txt` containing your data for my testing.

This assumes that the character-string within `[...]` is always purely numeric and 0..999999999

If the string can be longer, a different comparison is required.

It's not clear whether you want the numerical value or the string that has the highest numerical value, so you get both. If `maxraw` is undefined, then `maxnum` will be `0`.

Answer (score 1):

That is not really difficult.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "MaxNumber=0"
for /F "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%V in (Example.txt) do (
    if not "%%V"=="" (
        for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%N in ("%%V") do if %%N GTR !MaxNumber! set "MaxNumber=%%N"
    )
)
echo Biggest number is: %MaxNumber%
endlocal
```

For details on the used commands, execute in a command prompt window

- `for /?` or `help for`
- `if /?` or `help if`
- `set /?` or `help set`
- `setlocal /?` or `help setlocal`

The line for removing leading zeros was taken from [Remove leading zeros in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14768917/3074564).

**EDIT:**

I moved the **for** loop to remove trailing zeros into the other loop to avoid that a number is interpreted as octal number. Thanks to [dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053/dbenham) for this hint.

Comment: is it possible to removing leading zeros with this @Mofi ?

Comment: Not near a computer so unable to test.  But wouldn't `set /a Number*=1` be an easier and more efficient way to strip leading zeroes from an integer?

Comment: @rojo - No, because 0 prefixed numbers are interpreted as octal - not what you want. It will completely fail with numbers like 08 or 09, but a number like 010 would be interpreted as decimal 8.

Comment: Actually, this answer doesn't work for the same reason. IF 09 GTR 8 evaluates to FALSE because of octal issues. An invalid octal value forces a string comparison. Since all numbers are fixed width, can use `if "%%V" gtr "!Number!"` instead.

Comment: @dbenham @Magoo I found a great way to strip leading zeroes off an integer.  `cmd /c exit /b %Number%`, then `set Number=%ERRORLEVEL%`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your number is always within the first set of square brackets, and assuming the numbers never exceed 2147483647, then you could use:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "max=0"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%A in (example.txt) do (
  for /f "tokens=* delims=0" %%B in ("%%A") do if %%B gtr !max! set "max=%%B"
)
echo max=%max%
```

The first loop extracts the number from between the brackets. The second loop strips any leading zeros. Not only has this been requested by the OP, but it is critical in order for the IF statement to interpret the number properly. IF will treat numbers with leading zeros as octal notation, which would give the wrong result. Lines with a value of 0 will be completely skipped. But that is OK, even if all values are 0, because max is initialized to 0.

If any of the values can exceed 2147483647, or if the above is slow because the input file is really large, then I would use my [JSORT.BAT utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5595) that can properly sort non-negative integers of up to 20 digits and quickly return a single line with the highest value. [JSORT.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5595) is hybrid JScript/batch script that will run on any Windows machine from XP onward.

This will only work if the numbers are never negative. It should be significantly faster if the input file is large.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "max=0"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%A in (
  'type example.txt ^| jsort /d "[" /t 2 /n /r /c 1'
) do for /f "tokens=* delims=0" %%B in ("%%A") do set "max=%%B"
echo max=%max%
```