# Batch File Input Error?

Tags: batch-file

I have an issue with batch file as you can see. I have tried searching for hours but, I did not find anything related to my question. So here is my code (English is not my first language so, please bear with me):

```
:fileexist
For %%f in ("bin/*.exe") do (
set /A count+=1
set c!count!=%%f
)
Set "input="
Set /P input= Select 
If "!input!" GTR "!count!" (Goto :fileexist)
If "!input!" EQU "0" (Set Exe=No executable file) & (Goto :nofileexist)
If "!input!" LSS "1" (Goto :fileexist)
If "!input!" LEQ "!count!" (Set Exe=!c%input%!) & (Goto :gotfile)
Goto :fileexist
```

Now i have three (3) executable files in that folder (bin) by default which is just an example as the client would have more than 3 or maybe less. Now let go with the example, The code works fine if i input correctly (1, 2 or 3) and selects the file but, if i input (12, 13, 14..) it still selects the 1st file note that this works with any number as long as the first digit is "1".

Similarly if i input (21, 22, 23..and so on) it selects the 2nd file and same with this, it will work with any number as long as the first digit is "2" but, now comes the "3" and guess what? It will not accept any higher number than that whether its (31, 32 ,4000..or so..) any number above "3" is not accepted and that's what i want but, I also want it to not accept other digits like the (12, 1400, 23, 27553.. etc).

I spent hours trying to figure it out but no luck that's why this is my last hope which involves the following:

- Replaced the delayed expansion from the "!input!" to "%input%".
- Replace Greater/Less Than/Equal signs.
- Set quotes around set command inside the loop.
- Tried to remove hidden spaces that set command creates (even with the quotes around it) with something similar to this %count:- %.
- And more with no possible luck..

I am sorry for the wall of text and for my English, of course. Please let me know if something is confusing and thank you for your time looking into this. It would be much appreciated if we all could figure out the root of this cause and came up with a solution. Thank you.

Comment: Try removing the quotes in the if statements. I'm posting from my phone so I can't test this, but I think they're making the code do string comparison instead of a numerical comparison.

Comment: @SomethingDark: Thank you very much for the quick response and the fix. Sorry for my previous response, a bit misunderstanding (I thought you said remove the quotes in the post). My mistake. But after rereading your post i realized you meant remove the quotes from the actual code so, I did that and voila. It worked right after removing the quotes. Thank you very much sir. Thank you.

Comment: Editing your title to add (Solved) is inappropriate here. If the answer you received solved the problem for you, indicate so by accepting it. If you found a solution a different way, add your own answer (in the appropriate space below) and share the solution so that others can benefit from it. Putting (Solved) in the subject (or editing to add the solution in the question itself) is not the proper way to do things here.

Comment: @Ken White: I sincerely apologize for that. I'll make sure it will never happen again. I got the solution from the user (SomethingDark) as you can probably see. I don't know how to accept that as an answer, Maybe you could tell me?

Comment: No need to apologize. I was just explaining. :-) You can't accept @SomethingDark's comment as an answer; hopefully SomethingDark will come back and make it one. If no one does after some time, you can add an answer yourself and mention where you got it (in the comment above) . Answering your own question is perfectly acceptable here - see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information.

Comment: @Ken White Thank you for the link. Hopefully (@SomethingDark) will post soon or I'll just edit the post with the answer and credit him for that. Cheers.

Comment: No, don't *edit the post with the answer*. Add your own answer, in the space for that provided below. I've already explained that you should **not** add *Solved* **or edit your question to include the answer**. Questions are questions, and **answers are answers**, and they each have their own places. See the bottom of the page where it says **1 Answer**? That's the area where **Answers** go. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite: Honest mistake. Should have been more careful when reading that. Answers go where the belong to (In the space below), Yes sir, got it. Thank you, Will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch variables are treated like strings unless they're explicitly treated like numbers. In this case, the quotes in your `if` statements are forcing the variables to be treated like strings since quotes aren't integers. Because of this, a string comparison is being done where the variables are being compared one character at a time, which means that 12 comes before 2 since 1 is less than 2.

```
If !input! GTR !count! (Goto :fileexist)
If !input! EQU 0 (Set Exe=No executable file) & (Goto :nofileexist)
If !input! LSS 1 (Goto :fileexist)
If !input! LEQ !count! (Set Exe=!c%input%!) & (Goto :gotfile)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a batch code based on your batch code with lots of verifications on entered user input.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

:RunAgain
set "Count=0"
for %%F in ("bin\*.exe") do (
    set /A Count+=1
    set "File!count!=%%~fF"
)

:EnterNumber
rem Define as default value a double quote.
set "Input=""
rem Ask user for entering a number.
set /P "Input=Enter number between 0 and %Count%: "

rem Remove double quotes if entered by user if entered anything at all.
rem This removal of all double quotes in entered string would result in
rem a syntax error if default value for Input is not a double quote and
rem the batch user hits just RETURN or ENTER without entering anything.
set "Input=%Input:"=%"

rem Let user enter the number again if nothing was entered by the user.
if not defined Input goto EnterNumber

rem Check if entered string consists of only digits, i.e. is a positive number.
set "NoneDigit="
for /F "delims=0123456789" %%N in ("%Input%") do set "NoneDigit=1"
rem Let user enter the number again if entered string was not a positive number.
if defined NoneDigit goto EnterNumber

rem Remove leading zeros to avoid number being interpreted as octal number.
set "Number="
for /f "tokens=* delims=0" %%N in ("%Input%") do set "Number=%%N"

rem Is the entered number 0?
if not defined Number (
    set "Executable=No executable file"
    goto NoExecutable
)

rem Has the user entered a too large number.
if %Number% GTR %Count% goto EnterNumber

set "Executable=!File%Number%!"
echo Selected EXE is: %Executable%
rem Do whatever should be done with this executable.
goto RunAgain

:NoExecutable
echo No executable selected.

:ExitBatch
endlocal
```

The comment lines starting with command **rem** (yes, it is a command) should explain the important blocks.

The loop for removing leading zeros was taken from answers on [Remove leading zeros in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762813/).

For more details on this batch code open a command prompt window, enter the following commands, and read the help output for each command.

1. `for /?`
2. `goto /?`
3. `if /?`
4. `set /?`
5. `setlocal /?`

Comment: I am really thankful for the input you have come forward with (Great support from the community). I learned something new today and for that I have you to thank to (Great explanation on each command there). I can clearly see you have put a lot of effort into the code but, As you can see i have got my own code to get working and its working perfectly fine, just as i wanted it to. Although I'll upvote on your answer (At Rep 15) as useful because I did find it very useful, Indeed. Thank you again sir and I apologize for not utilizing your code but, I did learn something new so that's a plus