# Check if file is older than 2 minutes

Tags: batch-file, executable

I want to check if a file "test.txt" is older than two minutes.

What I have so far is the possibility to check the current timestamp of the machine and the last modified date of the file.

But how to substract now from the current machine time to check if the file is older than two minutes?

```
set mytimestamp="%date:~0,2%.%date:~3,2%.%date:~6,4% 

%time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%"

echo %mytimestamp%

SET filename="test.txt"
FOR %%f IN (%filename%) DO SET filedatetime="%%~tf"
::echo %filedatetime%


IF %filedatetime% == %mytimestamp% goto same

goto notsame


:same
ECHO "files same"
goto :eof

:notsame 
ECHO "files not same"
goto :eof


:eof
```

Comment: Have you checked `set /a variable = arithmetic-expression` ?

Comment: I'have seen it before, but I dont know how to use it. Where to substract it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
set hh=%TIME:~0,2%
set mm=%TIME:~3,2%
set ss=%TIME:~6,2%

set /a sum_sec=%hh% * 3600 + %mm% * 60 + %ss% -120

set /a h=%sum_sec% / 3600
set /a m=(%sum_sec%/60) - 60 * %h%
set /a s=%sum_sec% - 60 * (%sum_sec%/60)
IF %h% LSS 10 set h=0%h%
IF %m% LSS 10 set m=0%m%
IF %s% LSS 10 set s=0%s%

set new_time=%h%:%m%:%s%

forfiles /P "C:\SomePath" /S /M test.txt /C "cmd /c if @ftime LSS %new_time% del /F /Q @path"
```

In this example we are deleting the file test.txt if it is older than 2 minutes. You can vary the time in the line `set /a sum_sec=%hh% * 3600 + %mm% * 60 + %ss% -120` by replacing 120 by any other value (in sec).

Comment: Will this work one minute after midnight for a file which was created one minute before midnight?

Comment: @MichaelS, this would be interesting for me, too.

Answer (score 2):

As usual, I go overboard on stuff.

**dt2epoch.bat -- local date/time to Unix epoch (seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC)**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if "%~1" equ "" (echo.dt2epoch.bat: usage: missing {year}.& exit /b 1)
if "%~2" equ "" (echo.dt2epoch.bat: usage: missing {month}.& exit /b 1)
if "%~3" equ "" (echo.dt2epoch.bat: usage: missing {day}.& exit /b 1)
if "%~4" equ "" (echo.dt2epoch.bat: usage: missing {hour}.& exit /b 1)
if "%~5" equ "" (echo.dt2epoch.bat: usage: missing {minute}.& exit /b 1)
if "%~6" equ "" (echo.dt2epoch.bat: usage: missing {second}.& exit /b 1)
if "%~7" neq "" (echo.dt2epoch.bat: usage: too many arguments.& exit /b 1)

set year=%~1
set month=%~2
set day=%~3
set hour=%~4
set minute=%~5
set second=%~6

rem remove leading zeroes, which set /a stupidly takes as octal (see <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762813/remove-leading-zeros-in-batch-file>)
for /f "tokens=* delims=0" %%i in ("!year!") do set year=%%i
for /f "tokens=* delims=0" %%i in ("!month!") do set month=%%i
for /f "tokens=* delims=0" %%i in ("!day!") do set day=%%i
for /f "tokens=* delims=0" %%i in ("!hour!") do set hour=%%i
for /f "tokens=* delims=0" %%i in ("!minute!") do set minute=%%i
for /f "tokens=* delims=0" %%i in ("!second!") do set second=%%i
rem echo.!year!-!month!-!day! !hour!:!minute!:!second!

rem get the (negative of the) local time zone offset
set i=0
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('w32tm /tz') do (
    set line[!i!]=%%i
    set /a i+=1
)
set /a ntzo=!line[0]:~-28,-24!
if "!line[0]:~0,40!" equ "Time zone: Current:TIME_ZONE_ID_DAYLIGHT" set /a ntzo+=!line[2]:~-28,-25!
rem echo.ntzo=!ntzo!

rem month days and cumulative past month days lookup
set MDAYS[1]=31
set MDAYS[2]=28
set MDAYS[3]=31
set MDAYS[4]=30
set MDAYS[5]=31
set MDAYS[6]=30
set MDAYS[7]=31
set MDAYS[8]=31
set MDAYS[9]=30
set MDAYS[10]=31
set MDAYS[11]=30
set MDAYS[12]=31
set CPMDAYS[1]=0
set /a CPMDAYS[2]=MDAYS[1]
set /a CPMDAYS[3]=CPMDAYS[2]+MDAYS[2]
set /a CPMDAYS[4]=CPMDAYS[3]+MDAYS[3]
set /a CPMDAYS[5]=CPMDAYS[4]+MDAYS[4]
set /a CPMDAYS[6]=CPMDAYS[5]+MDAYS[5]
set /a CPMDAYS[7]=CPMDAYS[6]+MDAYS[6]
set /a CPMDAYS[8]=CPMDAYS[7]+MDAYS[7]
set /a CPMDAYS[9]=CPMDAYS[8]+MDAYS[8]
set /a CPMDAYS[10]=CPMDAYS[9]+MDAYS[9]
set /a CPMDAYS[11]=CPMDAYS[10]+MDAYS[10]
set /a CPMDAYS[12]=CPMDAYS[11]+MDAYS[11]

set /a pastLeapDays=(year-1968)/4-(year-1900)/100+(year-1600)/400
if "!month!" equ "0" (set leap=0) else if "!month!" equ "1" (set leap=0) else if "!month!" equ "2" (set leap=0) else (set /a leap="!(year%4)-!(year%100)+!(year%400)")
set /a cpmDays=CPMDAYS[!month!]
set /a epoch=((((year-1970)*365+pastLeapDays+cpmDays+leap+day-1)*24+hour)*60+minute+ntzo)*60+second
rem echo.!epoch! (pastLeapDays=!pastLeapDays! cpmDays=!cpmDays! leap=!leap! ntzo=!ntzo!)

echo.!epoch!

exit /b 0
```

**epoch.bat -- Unix epoch for current date/time**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if "%~1" neq "" (echo.epoch.bat: usage: too many arguments.& exit /b 1)

call dt2epoch.bat !date:~0,4! !date:~5,2! !date:~8,2! !time:~0,2! !time:~3,2! !time:~6,2!

exit /b 0
```

**modepoch.bat -- Unix epoch for file modification timestamp**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if "%~1" equ "" (echo.modepoch.bat: usage: missing {filename}.& exit /b 1)
if "%~2" neq "" (echo.modepoch.bat: usage: too many arguments.& exit /b 1)

if not exist "%~1" (echo.modepoch.bat: usage: file "%~1" does not exist.& exit /b 1)

set dt=%~t1
set year=!dt:~0,4!
set month=!dt:~5,2!
set day=!dt:~8,2!
set hour=!dt:~11,2!
set minute=!dt:~14,2!
rem unfortunately, file mod timestamp doesn't come with seconds; just set to zero
set second=00

call dt2epoch.bat !year! !month! !day! !hour! !minute! !second!

exit /b 0
```

**modage.bat -- seconds elapsed since file modification timestamp**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if "%~1" equ "" (echo.modage.bat: usage: missing {filename}.& exit /b 1)
if "%~2" neq "" (echo.modage.bat: usage: too many arguments.& exit /b 1)

set fileName=%~1
if not exist "!fileName!" (echo.modage.bat: usage: file "!fileName!" does not exist.& exit /b 1)

for /f %%i in ('epoch.bat') do set epoch=%%i
for /f %%i in ('modepoch.bat "!fileName!"') do set modepoch=%%i

set /a diff=epoch-modepoch
echo.!diff!

exit /b 0
```

**checkage.bat -- test if file (modification) is older or younger than given number of seconds**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if "%~1" equ "" (echo.checkage.bat: usage: missing {filename}.& exit /b 1)
if "%~2" equ "" (echo.checkage.bat: usage: missing {age}.& exit /b 1)
if "%~3" neq "" (echo.checkage.bat: usage: too many arguments.& exit /b 1)

set fileName=%~1
if not exist "!fileName!" (echo.checkage.bat: usage: file "!fileName!" does not exist.& exit /b 1)
set age=%~2

for /f %%i in ('modage.bat "!fileName!"') do set modage=%%i

set /a diff=modage-age
if "!diff:~0,1!" neq "-" goto older
goto younger

:older
echo.older
goto eof

:younger
echo.younger
goto eof

:eof
exit /b 0
```

These scripts are currently working on my system based on a fair amount of testing, but there are a number of caveats that must be mentioned:

- The `epoch.bat` script hard-codes an assumption of the format of the system `!date!` and `!time!`, which are configurable in Control Panel (at least the `!date!` is). For example, I've set my date format to `yyyy-MM-dd`, but IIRC, that's not the default. You'll have to adjust the substring expansions if your format differs.
- The `modepoch.bat` script hard-codes an assumption of the format of the file modification timestamp returned by `%~t1`. I believe the same caveat applies about the configurability of the date/time format here.
- As you can see in `modepoch.bat`, seconds are not returned by `%~t1`, and I haven't been able to get my system to return seconds. Thus I've had to hard-code zero for the seconds field. This can result in some quirky behavior from the `modage.bat` script; specifically, if you touch a file and then instantaneously get its age, you could get anything from 0 to 59, because the script is forced to make the assumption that the file was last modified at the start (seconds=0) of whatever minute it was modified in.
- As part of `dt2epoch.bat`, I attempt to get the current local time zone offset by parsing the output of `w32tm /tz`. This is necessary in order to convert from local time to UTC, as the Unix epoch is defined as seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 *UTC*. Needless to say, that's probably a very brittle component of this code. Furthermore, it looks to me from the output of that utility that the time zone data underlying its output can support a degree of flexibility that I didn't bother to attempt to parse in my code (and, frankly, probably wouldn't have been able to using pure Dosbatch, for that matter). For example, it looks like there can be a standard time bias, and possibly more than two (i.e. more than just the standard and daylight) time zone offsets for a single time zone. But my code only parses the base time zone offset and the additional daylight time offset, and makes some pretty tight assumptions about those output lines. This particular component of the code may not work for you. Fortunately, you could easily get rid of it, and although the resulting epoch values would not be perfectly accurate, comparisons between such inaccurate values should still be correct.

Despite all of the above (rather significant) caveats, this code is working for me on my current system; I'm getting perfect agreement between my Unix (Cygwin) `date` utility (specifically, `date +%s`) and the output of `epoch.bat`, and the modification timestamp and comparison stuff appears to be working as well.

Use this code if you dare.

Comment: Wow, this is a amazing coding. I'll try that out too.

Comment: PLEASE UPVOTE THIS ANSWER! If not for anything else, then at least for the effort!  (Basically, I think it proves my point about it all **not** being a reasonable thing to do in a windows batch file, but man, wow! Respect!)

Answer (score 1):

The way this would normally be done would be by converting the two times into time coordinates, (regular numeric values expressing time as a number of time units, say minutes, since a fixed point in time in the past, known as "epoch",) subtracting the desired offset (2 minutes in your case) from the second time coordinate, and then comparing the two time coordinates as numbers.

Unfortunately, it is extremely difficult to take a textual (human-readable) timestamp as given by the windows date and time commands and convert it to a time coordinate.  Even if you go through all the trouble of extracting the year number, the month number, the day-of-the-month, the hour, and the minute, and concatenating all those into something that looks like a number, you still cannot treat it like a number, because for example subtracting 2 from 201504170001 gives 201504169999, not 201504162359.

So, in order for it to work you would have to use numeric multiplication and addition instead of string concatenation, meaning that you would have to multiply the year number by the number of minutes in a year, and add to it the month number multiplied by the number of minutes in a month, and then add to it the day-of-the-month multiplied by the number of minutes in a day, and so on, but in order to do that you would first have to know whether each month has 30 or 31 days, and it gets further complicated by the fact that February may have 28 or 29 days depending on whether it is a leap year.

So, I would say, forget it.  This is not something that is reasonable to do in a windows batch file.  Write a small program in a real programming language instead, or find a way to accomplish what you are trying to do without having to check whether the timestamp of a file is older than an amount of time.