# Batch compare int's rather than strings

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a script that parses an integer from a string, and for values less than 10 the parsed integer is 01, 02, 03... so when I try to compare it to an integer value less than 10, it compares, for example 09 and 9. If they are compared as integers the value is the same, but they are being compared as strings so they are not the same. So how can I force batch to compare the integer values?

Here is some sample code:

```
@echo off 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set str=10:04:01
set str=!str:~3,2!
set num=4
echo str: !str!
echo num: !num!
if !num! geq !str! (
    if !num leq !str! (
        echo they are equal
    )
)
```

The output is:

```
str: 04
num: 4
```

and I would like the output to be:

```
str: 04
num: 4
they are equal
```

Comment: Use `set /a str=1%str:~3,2%-100`. Possible duplicate of [Remove leading zeros in batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762813/remove-leading-zeros-in-batch-file)

Comment: Thanks, this works, but is it possible to force the comparison to be integer value? thus not requiring leading zeros to be removed? I might need to do a textual comparison later on, and so will still need the leading zero's. I know I could just create a duplicate value before removing zeros, but this becomes cumbersome.

Comment: Well you can prepend with `0` in case of a single digit but if you have two then it'll mess the comparison up, so no, only a duplicate variable is the solution.

Comment: You said "If 09 and 9 are compared as integers the value is the same". This is _not_ true. An _integer_ value that start in 0 is taken as an octal number, so 09 is an _invalid_ octal integer. This means that if a way "to force the comparison to be integer value" would be used, you just would get an error message. Try this: `set /A nine=09` and this: `if 7 equ 07 echo True`

Comment: Another example: `if 011 EQU 9 echo True` to illustrate useful @Aacini's comment.